# Django - setting a model pk to None and saving returns "ValueError: Cannot force an update in save() with no primary key."

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have already figured this out but I could not find an answer to this and will post because somebody might find it helpful.

Here is the code that was causing problems:

models.py

```
class SModelQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def stubbed_outputs(self):
        return self.defer("outputs").annotate(
            has_outputs=models.Case(
                models.When(
                    models.Q(~models.Q(outputs={}) & models.Q(outputs__isnull=False)),
                    then=True,
                ),
                default=False,
                output_field=models.BooleanField(),
            )
        )

    def for_user(self, user):
        return self.filter(user=user)


class SModelManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return SModelsQuerySet(self.model, using=self._db).stubbed_outputs()

    def for_user(self, user):
        return self.get_queryset().for_user(user)


class OutputsManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super().get_queryset().only("outputs")

    def for_user(self, user):
        return self.get_queryset().filter(user=user)


class SModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, db_index=True)

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True, blank=True)

    inputs = models.JSONField(default=dict)
    outputs = models.JSONField(default=dict)

    objects = SModelManager()
    outputs_objects = OutputsManager()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "scientific models"
        db_table = "smodels"
        managed = False

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

views.py

```
class SharedModelViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = serializers.SharedModelSerializer

    @action(detail=True, methods=["post"])
    def save(self, request, pk=None):
        shared_model = self.get_object()
        model = get_object_or_404(
            models.SModel.objects.filter(user=shared_model.share_from),
            pk=shared_model.model_to_share_id,
        )
        model.pk = None
        model.user_id = shared_model.share_to.id
        model.save()

        shared_model.delete()

        return Response(
            serializers.SModelSerializer(model).data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK
        )
```

When this view was trying to save, I was getting an error like this: `"ValueError: Cannot force an update in save() with no primary key."` I could not figure this out and it was working a few weeks ago.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem: The query which was returning the model - only there to check that the shared model was indeed shared by a user with access to share it - had deferred fields. These fields are deferred because they are massive json objects that take a long time to query.

The Solution: To add a separate manager models.Manager to return queries with all fields. Then the model saves just fine.